# Using barcode scanner with Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, barcode-scanner, point-of-sale, keypreview

I'm developing a POS (pet project) and I'm thinking of adding a bar code scanner to capture the sales faster. I do not have a scanner at the moment with me, and would like to ask some questions, as I'm stuck a bit.

On the sales screen my initial idea was to have an `TEdit` component and when a person scans the product it would fill the `TEdit` with the string. Now the problem I'm encountering is that I want to make the `TEdit` invisible so that the person does not see it. But once you make the `TEdit` invisible, you cannot set focus on it, so that plan cannot work.

So can anyone suggest what I can use to "capture" the scanned string? How would I make the component to listen and wait for the scanner? I assume that the scanner would be like a normal keyboard event, like button down or up.

Comment: Barcode scanners usually appear to send keystrokes, so you can _handle_ it in the same way you handle the keyboard. If you don't want to have a visible Edit, you can handle the keystrokes at the form level with the OnKey Up/Down/Press events.

Comment: I understand, but what will I use to capture the string of the barcode as soon as there is a OnKey event. With an TEdit it is easy as I could just let the string appear in the TEdit and take it from there.

Comment: It turns out question has little to do with barcode scanner, but more with "how to receive text with no focused control". Is that right?

Comment: @Krom Yes that would be a much better question.

Comment: There are some barcode scanners which can bypass the "keyboard wedge" and you can connect your program directly to the barcode scanner device, which appears as a serial port to your program. I find this superior to HID/keyboard wedge for SOME applications. Just putting the info out there for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a TEdit with a height and width of 0 so it won't appears and make sure it get focused when you scan your barcode.

Answer (score 6):

There's [KeyPreview](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.KeyPreview) property on TForm. Set it to true, so all key presses are processed by form first before controls.

Article about keyboard processing in Delphi: http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/keyboard_events.htm

Related SO question: [How does Delphi's KeyPreview work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509242/how-does-delphis-keypreview-work)

Answer (score 6):

What I have done is use the KeyPreview to monitor for a function key like F9 which the bar code scanner is set to prefix scans with. When this is received, I pop up a dialog with a single edit box and OK button. This then receives the rest of the barcode information, and the scanner ends the entry with the Enter key. I can then determine the purpose of the scanned data (in my case, one type starts with a prefix) and then put the data into the appropriate field on my main form.

I chose F9 because it seems inert in most applications, so you can use the scanner in other ways, but I support other keys too for flexibility. My application also has a scanner test mode where it shows the keys sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can also place the TEdit outside of the visible window, setting the component's Top and Left properties to something like -50. You can then set focus to it just like a regular visible TEdit box, but it will be invisible to the user.