# Keyboard hook to look for F12 with delphi

Tags: delphi, setwindowshookex

This question may have already been answered but I've been unable to find the proper response. I'm trying to turn toggle a debug switch when the F12 key is pressed in a form. I'm unable to use the onkeydown event since I would have to setup a separate function for each field along with the form. So I've researched and found the SetWindowsHookEx function to set a keyboard hook. This working well except I'm getting two indications the F12 key has been press each time it is pressed:

```
2014/05/21 14:16:43.334
Code: 0
Key: 123
KeyStroke: 5767169
KeyStroke to Hex: 00580001
2014/05/21 14:16:43.446
Code: 0
Key: 123
KeyStroke: -1067974655
KeyStroke to Hex: C0580001  Note: this should be the keystroke that reflects KEYDOWN
```

I see the Keystroke is a possible method to check for keydown (WM_KEYDOWN $0100). My question is how do I test Keystroke for WM_KEYDOWN?

Here is my callback function:

```
function KeyboardHookProc(Code: Integer; Key: Word; KeyStroke: LongInt) : LongInt;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Code = HC_NOREMOVE then exit;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(FkbHook, Code,Key,KeyStroke);
  if Code < 0  then exit;

{
WM_KEYDOWN

}
  if (KeyStroke and WM_KEYDOWN) = 0 then { this is where I need to test but this doesn't work! }
  begin
  if Code = HC_ACTION then
  begin
    case Key of
      vk_F12: begin
          TKPMF.Memo1.Lines.Add(FormatDatetime('yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss.zzz',now));
          TKPMF.Memo1.Lines.Add('Code: ' + IntToStr(Code));
          TKPMF.Memo1.Lines.Add('Key: ' + IntToStr(Key));
          TKPMF.Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyStroke: ' + IntToStr(KeyStroke));
          TKPMF.Memo1.Lines.Add('KeyStroke to Hex: ' + LongToHex(KeyStroke));
      end;
    end; {case}

  end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using? Why not use the form's KeyPreview? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6509242/how-does-delphis-keypreview-work

Comment: At the worst case use an ApplicationEvents. No need to hook  your own application.

Comment: Not sure why anyone would downvote here. The OP showed evidence of research, and example code. The OP is also new (rep=1), so the failure to clarify Delphi version is excusable.

Comment: +1. There's no reason for a downvote here. Sufficient information and effort (including code) was provided, and the specific Delphi version is irrelevant, as the `KeyPreview` and `OnKeyDown` events have existed since Delphi 1 and still exist in the VCL `TForm` in XE6.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do not need to assign a different handler to each individual control's `OnKeyDown` event. You can assign all of them to use the same single handler. If you enable the form's `KeyPreview` property then you won't need to assign a handler to any of the control's at all, you can use the Form's `OnKeyDown` event by itself.  If you need to detect the key press when you have multiple forms open, you can use the `TApplication.OnMessage` or `TApplicationEvents.OnMessage` event instead.  Either way, you do not need to use a keyboard hook via `SetWindowsHooKEx()` at all.

The reason your hook is not working is because `WM_KEYDOWN` is a window message, not a Keystroke flag. [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Keystroke of the two messages you showed differ only in bits 30 (previous key state) and 31 (transition state).

Comment: Remy, yes that was it, like usual, I try to make things too complicated. I can always count on you to know the correct answer.

Comment: When someone gives you a correct answer, you should click the button to accept it (only works for one if there is more than one answer).  That way, the answerer gets a small increase in reputation, like you did when a few of us upvoted your question, and the answer acquires a green tick, which helps other users.